# SQL Server and DataSet

Tags: .net

I created a simple DataSet in .NET that connects to SQL Server Table.

I try to create new rows in the table but I do not see any changes in the table
(in the `Server Explorer -> right click on the tablbe -> View Table Data`)

My code go like this :

```
public bool CreateCustomer(Customer customer)
{

    var r = _BDSet.Customer.NewCustomerRow();

    r.CustomerId = 0;
    r.Name = "idan";
    r.CustomerDetailsId = 7;
    _BDSet.Customer.AddCustomerRow(r);

    _customerAdptr.Fill(_BDSet.Customer);
    _customerAdptr.Update(_BDSet.Customer);

    return true;
 }
```

Comment: Just a wild guess: Because you Fill the DataTable prior to update, you'll loose all your changes.

Comment: `_customerAdptr.Fill(_BDSet.Customer);` throw away all your addRow. Probably you don't need this line because _DBSet is already filled.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line before  `return true;`   :

```
_customerAdptr.AcceptChanges();
```